# Can I drop files on a DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, file, datagrid

I have a datgrid that has the information of files. The name, type of file, size... etc.

I would like to do the following:

1.- select some files, one or more in the file explorer in windows.
2.- drop the files into the datagrid.
3.- With the path of the files, I can convert this information in the type of items of the dataGrid, so I can create an object myFile, set the properties with the info and add the object to the collection that the dataGrid use as ItemsSource.
4.- One with of all the information in the dataGrid, I use my repositury to save the new items in the dataGrid in the database.

My question is if I can drop files in a datagrid, and if it is possible, hoe can I know the path of the files.

I have look at the e argument of the drop event but I don't see what information I receive in the event.

Thanks.
Daimroc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can try this soulution.........................](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/draganddrop/drag-and-drop-with-windows-explorer.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. The solution is with textBox, but gives ideas. Thanks.